# Getting duct tape residue off of bare drywall

Tags: drywall

Is there any way to remove duct tape residue from bare (unprimered) drywall without damaging the paper surface?  I assume this would be necessary prior to priming? Or not?

Answer (score 1):

From [WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Duct-Tape-Residue)

> Duct tape is a powerful adhesive, but it leaves behind a strong, sticky residue. Fortunately, there are tricks you can use to remove most residue with ease. Both rubbing alcohol and cooking oil are effective methods that can be followed up with soap and warm water to clean most surfaces. For stubborn stains, heat the area up with a hairdryer or apply an alternative cleaning product and your surface will soon be back to normal again.

More extensive details are in the article.

Another [site](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/how-to-remove-duct-tape-residue/)

> **Your Options**
> Scraping
> Warm water
> Rubbing alcohol
> Lubricant like WD-40
> Hair dryer

Comment: Good ideas. Except for cooking oil. Cooking oil is probably a reasonable choice on a hard, relatively non-porous, horizontal surface - e.g., most kitchen counters. But on drywall it would be a disaster - soak into the paper, drip down the wall, very hard to remove in order to have a paintable surface.

Comment: Most of the other options listed also sound like they'd cause damage to drywall paper. Heating with a hair dryer and _gentle_ scraping with a plastic putty knife (so as to minimize the chances of tearing up the paper) sound like the most likely options.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would probably go with sanding. You do want to remove any adhesive residue, as it will mess with your paint and also may add unwanted surface texture. If you have to sand more than a little bit, you might then need to skim coat the drywall in order to hide the marks from the  sanding. I don't expect things to go that far though, unless the duct tape is particularly aggressive. A fine sanding sponge should make quick work of prepping the surface for primer.